# Unit testing the repository. NHibernate

Tags: c#, unit-testing, repository, sql-server-ce, unit-of-work

I've got `NHibernate`-based (constructor `ISessionFactory` injection) generic repository implementation which is stored inside `DAL`. It implements contract which is stored in `Domain Layer'.

Should I test real repository behavior using `SQl CE` or should I refactor my application to support agnostic-like (like in Tim Maccharty's book http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/productCd-0470147563,descCd-authorInfo.html) `Unit of Work` and then give my fake implementation of `IUnitOfWorkRepository`?

Is it a valid approach to run tests on a local database exposing real repository implementation?

Thanks!

Comment: check ayendes blog for unit test nhibernate

Comment: @blindmeis Thanks! That's a great article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is what your are testing and why. That will answer the question.

If:

**I want to test a third party tool**

That is, are you testing if NHibernate is working (not a kind of test
I do). Then do whatever it requires, so refactoring not required. Loose yourself.

**I want to test how my code interacts with a thrid party tool**

Then you are talking about what I like to call a interaction test. Refactoring is required as your more interested in how your using NHiberate than if it works.

**I want to test my code**

The abstract NHibernate entirely. Do whatever is necessary ... wrapper? Your now back into unit testing.

**I want to test my application from a user point of view**

I think this is above the scope your talking. But you can use this scope talking about components. So ... hmmm ... worthwhile but not easy. Not a unit test, so you want to instantiate the component/app and run the whole thing as its 'user' does. I call these 'UATs' and usually implement as 'Coded UATs'.

Comment: I have no embedded validation logic inside the repository. So that's true I need to test the interaction between code and the tool. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A unit test is testing a unit in isolation. So, no, it's not even a unit test if you're going to the database.
Abstract away and test your repositories with mocked up interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

I think to test the repositories you need to use the actual scenario. Otherwise you don't have any other place to test the database access. Mocking the repositories is not a good practice. Because you don't have any logic which is need to test in the repositories. I think you need to write integration tests which is calling actual repositories to have any benefit from it.

Comment: To test, yes. You should run integration tests against a live database. However, this question was on unit testing. Surely using a database is not testing in isolation?

Comment: Do you think there are any use of testing method calls of the repositories. Because I don't think repository has any logic needs to be tested.

Comment: It's a tough one really. There isn't a great deal of logic, that's true. However, there can be some processing and validation/verification that occurs when reading and writing from the DB. As well as parsing things and setting up all your objects.
So, you don't _have_ to unit test. But if you want the security then the best practice is to abstact and to test with a mocked interface.